# bluebird promisejs warning

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a node.js script which keeps giving this warning message. Any suggestions how shall i fix it ?

> ```
> at Promise._settlePromises (/root/TG/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
> ```
>
> │ │     at _drainQueueStep
>   (/root/TG/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
>   │ │     at _drainQueue
>   (/root/TG/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
>   │ │     at Async._drainQueues
>   (/root/TG/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
>   │ │     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate]
>   (/┌────────┐de_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)          │
>   │     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)                  │ 0:node │
>   │ │     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)                └────────┘ 
>   │

│     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)

Comment: I see a stack trace, but don't see the actual warning text.

Comment: Thats what i get, not sure if i shall be concerned abt it or not